# assigning a value to a class variable python

Tags: python, class, variables, variable-assignment

I have the following class which has two class variables  the "value" and the "gradient".I assign two values to the class variables and then print them out. But then I assign 20 to a class variable("limit") that doesn't exist. but the compiler is happy and it seems that stores the variable. How is this possible?
My assumption was that if the variable name was incorrect I should see an error message. shouldn't I ?

```
class wire:
    def __init__(self,value,gradient):
        self.value     = value
        self.gradient  = gradient

XX = wire(10,0.05)
print XX.value , XX.gradient

XX.limit = 20
print XX.value , XX.gradient, XX.limit
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You are assigning to *instance* attributes, not class attributes. No, Python doesn't limit this, this is perfectly normal behaviour.

Comment: Is this illegal in any other OO language or am I dreaming?

Comment: Don't confuse typing models with the programming paradigm. C++ and Java may make it illegal, but other languages don't. Python is a [dynamic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language), and you are thinking of static languages here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are instance variables, not class variables.

But I don't know why you expect an error. There is no difference between defining those attributes in `__init__` or anywhere else. Either way, you're adding new attributes to the instance.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the clarification, can we do the same thing in any other OO language? or is this python thing? I dont have a lot of experience in OO languages

Comment: As Martijn says, this very much depends on the language. Java is statically typed, so all variables including those on classes need to be declared first. Ruby prevents all access to attributes from outside the class unless you define accessors, but you can define them wherever you like inside the class, not just in the initialiser. And so on.